# Wrong Number of Products When Hiding Subcategory Products From Showing In Parent Category

Tags: php, categories

I'm using following code to display only parent category products and remove the child category products displayed in the catalog:

```
function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) {
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array( 
                                    array (
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                                        'include_children' => false
                                    ) 
                                 )
    );
  }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

If you now select the parent category in the catalog, only the products from this category are displayed.

The code works as it should except for one small flaw:
The number of products per catalog page is no longer correct and varies from page to page depending on how many products of the subcategory were hidden.

I could not find any further information about this problem although this code seems to be used more often.

Comment: those counts are inclusive, unlike your modified queries, you would need to recalculate these figures, and this is a slow/expensive operation which is normally cached by WordPress to avoid this cost. It would be more efficient to not show the counts

Comment: It is not so much about displaying the count as it is about displaying the same number of products on each page.

Comment: It looks like an empty sales shelf, although the warehouse is full enough.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you provided that would mean different pages return different numbers of posts, the only thing I would change is a check for `is_admin` and possibly changing `isset` to `! empty` in case `product_cat` is set but has a falsey value such as `null` or `''`, but neither of those, nor the code in your question, would result in differing posts per page across pagination